# Showing that a particular stochastic process is a martingale.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ be a probability space and
>   $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be independent random variables that are
>   positive valued and with mean equal to $1$. Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb
> > N}$ be the stochastic process $$X_n =\prod_{k=1}^n Y_k$$ Show that it
>   is a martingale with respect to the  filtration $(\mathcal F_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$generated by
>   $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$

My attempt:

I need to show that 
$$\int_F X_{n+1} dP=\int_F X_n dP$$
for any $F\in\mathcal F_n$.

I started by writing down the definition of $X_{n+1}$.

$$\int_F \prod_{k=1}^{n+1} Y_k dP=\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}\int 1_F  Y_k dP$$
(this first equality holds because of the independence of the $Y$'s.)
$$=\bigg(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\int 1_F  Y_k dP\bigg)\cdot\int 1_F Y_{n+1} dP$$

Now $\bigg(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\int 1_F  Y_k dP\bigg)$ equals by definition $\int_F X_n dP$.

Now since the $Y$'s are independent, and the filtration is the natural filtration,we have that $\mathcal F_n$ and $Y_{n+1}$ are independent, and hence
$1_F$ and $Y_{n+1}$ are independent (remember that $F$ is any $\mathcal F_n$-measurable set). But then I obtain

$$\int_F X_{n+1} dP=\bigg(\int_F X_n dP\bigg)\cdot \bigg(\int 1_F dP\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\int Y_{n+1}dP\bigg)$$

$$\int_F X_{n+1} dP=\bigg(\int_F X_n dP\bigg)\cdot P(F)$$
and hence we obtain a supermartingale instead.

Nevertheless I've seen another solution  that uses a different approach:

$$E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n]=E[X_{n}Y_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n]=X_nE[Y_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n]=X_nE[Y_{n+1}=X_n$$
By independence, and the fact that $Y_{n+1}$ is independent from the sigma algebra $\mathcal F_n$.

The approach seems quite similar, but I don't really see how to put them both together. 
Is there any mistake on my approach?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int (I_F X_n) Y_{N+1} dP=(\int X_n I_F dP) (\int Y_{n+1}dP)$ because  $Y_{n+1}$ and $X_n I_F$ are independent. In your argument you are aassuming independence of the triple $X_n, I_F, Y_{n+1}$. You cannot separate $P(F)$ because $X_n$ and $I_F$ are not indepedent.